# MechanicalSoup nothing to repeat at position 0

Tags: python

```
    import argparse
from getpass import getpass
import mechanicalsoup

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Login to Northwest.1")
parser.add_argument("username")
args = parser.parse_args()

args.password = getpass("Please enter your Northwest password: ")

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()

browser.open("https://thenorthwest.myatonce.com/login")
browser.select_form('#login-form')
browser["username"] = args.username
browser["password"] = args.password
resp = browser.submit_selected()
browser.follow_link("catalog")
browser.follow_link("?cl=45&gndr=65")
browser.launch_browser()
```

Well, uh. I can follow the link to catalog, https://thenorthwest.myatonce.com/catalog/ so there is no problem with login and forwarding to catalog but I cannot follow the link to the specified catalog page. https://thenorthwest.myatonce.com/catalog/?cl=45&gndr=65 Can anyone help?

**FULL ERROR CODE AND POSSIBLE FLASHBANG ALERT BELOW**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    browser.follow_link("login")
l_browser.py", line 354, in follow_link
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 324, in _find_link_internal
    return self.find_link(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 298, in find_link
    raise LinkNotFoundError()
mechanicalsoup.utils.LinkNotFoundError
PS C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls> py main.py anatoliawholesale
Please enter your Northwest password:
PS C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls> py main.py anatoliawholesale
Please enter your Northwest password: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    browser.follow_link("?cl=45&gndr=64")
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 354, in follow_link
    link = self._find_link_internal(link, bs4_args,
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 324, in _find_link_internal
    return self.find_link(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 296, in find_link
    links = self.links(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 281, in links
    all_links = [a for a in all_links
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 282, in <listcomp>
    if re.search(url_regex, a['href'])]
  File "C:\Users\emosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 200, in sea
rch
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 303, in _co
mpile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_compile.py", line 76
4, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
 in parse
  File "C:\Users\emosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 443,
 in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "C:\Users\emosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 668,
 in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
PS C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls> py main.py anatoliawholesale
Please enter your Northwest password:
PS C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls> py main.py anatoliawholesale
Please enter your Northwest password: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    browser.follow_link("?cl=45&gndr=65")
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 354, in follow_link
    link = self._find_link_internal(link, bs4_args,
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 324, in _find_link_internal
    return self.find_link(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 296, in find_link
    links = self.links(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 281, in links
    all_links = [a for a in all_links
  File "C:\Users\emosc\PycharmProjects\achyls\venv\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\statefu
l_browser.py", line 282, in <listcomp>
    if re.search(url_regex, a['href'])]
  File "C:\Users\emosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 200, in sea
rch
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 303, in _co
mpile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_compile.py", line 76
4, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 948,
 in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "C:\Users\emosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 443,
 in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "C:\Users\emosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 668,
 in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [mechanicalsoup tutorial](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)

> ```
> >>> browser.follow_link("forms")
> <Response [200]>
> >>> browser.url
> 'http://httpbin.org/forms/post'
> ```
>
> We passed a regular expression `"forms"` to `follow_link()`, who followed
> the link whose text matched this expression. There are many other ways
> to call `follow_link()`, but we’ll get back to it.

Which imply that what you deliver as 1st argument to `follow_link` is treated as pattern. You did

```
browser.follow_link("?cl=45&gndr=65")
```

note that `?` has special meaning in regular expression - zero or one of previous thing. There is not previous thing or in other words *nothing to repeat at position 0*. Please try using [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to alleviate this problem following way, add `import re` immediately before `import argparse` then replace

```
browser.follow_link("?cl=45&gndr=65")
```

using

```
browser.follow_link(re.escape("?cl=45&gndr=65"))
```